# Html form radio button not working

Tags: php, html, css, forms, radio-button

My index.php contains a bunch of php and javascript code, and html formatted in CSS. I'm not very experienced with CSS, but I don't think it would affect the usability of this html form. Here is the index code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Choose"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="choose "/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://i/favicon.ico"> 

    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="FullPageBackgroundImage/js/mootools.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="FullPageBackgroundImage/js/core.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="content">
<div id="poll">
<form>

<input id="ch1" type="radio" name="choice" value="0" />
<label for="ch1">
<?php echo $current['choice1']; ?>
</label>
<br />
<input id="ch2" type="radio" name="choice" value="1" />
<label for="ch2">
<?php echo $current['choice2']; ?>
</label>
</form>
</div>
hello

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**And this is the CSS:**

```
body {
    background-color:#000;
    background:#fff;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}

#top_header{
    width:100%;
    height:52px;
    background:#FFF;
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index:-1;

}

#logo{
    background-image:url('Images/web_buttons.jpg');
    position:fixed;
    top:3px;
    left:0px;
    width:366px;
    height:45px;

}

#display{
    background-image:url('Images/web_buttons.jpg');
    background-position: 0px -40px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:420px;
    width:57px;
    height:19px;

}

#display_divider{
    background-image:url('Images/web_buttons.jpg');
    background-position: -100px -45px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:477px;
    width:8px;
    height:50px;    
}

a.display_single{
    background-image:url('Images/web_buttons.jpg');
    background-position: 0px -80px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:485px;
    width:67px;
    height:26px;
}

a:hover.display_single{
    background-image:url('Images/web_buttons.jpg');
    background-position: 0px -104px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:485px;
    width:67px;
    height:26px;
}

a.display_multiple{
    background-image:url('Images/web_buttons.jpg');
    background-position: 0px -128px;
    position:fixed;
    top:26px;
    left:485px;
    width:86px;
    height:26px;
}
a:hover.display_multiple{
    background-image:url('Images/web_buttons.jpg');
    background-position: 0px -152px;
    position:fixed;
    top:26px;
    left:485px;
    width:86px;
    height:26px;
}

#view{
    background-image:url('Images/web_buttons.jpg');
    background-position: 0px -58px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:620px;
    width:37px;
    height:19px;    
}

#view_divider{
    background-image:url('Images/web_buttons.jpg');
    background-position: -100px -45px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:657px;
    width:8px;
    height:50px;    
}

a.view_WTFest{
    background-image:url('Images/web_buttons.jpg');
    background-position: 0px -178px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:665px;
    width:69px;
    height:26px;
}

a:hover.view_WTFest{
    background-image:url('Images/web_buttons.jpg');
    background-position: 0px -204px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:665px;
    width:69px;
    height:26px;
}

a.view_lamest{
    background-image:url('Images/web_buttons.jpg');
    background-position: 0px -228px;
    position:fixed;
    top:26px;
    left:665px;
    width:69px;
    height:25px;
}

a:hover.view_lamest{
    background-image:url('Images/web_buttons.jpg');
    background-position: 0px -253px;
    position:fixed;
    top:26px;
    left:665px;
    width:69px;
    height:25px;
}

a.view_latest{
    background-image:url('Images/web_buttons.jpg');
    background-position: 0px -275px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:734px;
    width:69px;
    height:25px;
}

a:hover.view_latest{
    background-image:url('Images/web_buttons.jpg');
    background-position: 0px -300px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:734px;
    width:69px;
    height:25px;

}

a.view_oldest{
    background-image:url('Images/web_buttons.jpg');
    background-position: 0px -323px;
    position:fixed;
    top:26px;
    left:734px;
    width:69px;
    height:26px;
}

a:hover.view_oldest{
    background-image:url('Images/web_buttons.jpg');
    background-position: 0px -348px;
    position:fixed;
    top:26px;
    left:734px;
    width:69px;
    height:25px;

}

a.submit_choices{
    background-image:url('Images/web_buttons.jpg');
    background-position: 0px -373px;
    position:fixed;
    top:3px;
    right:3px;
    width:164px;
    height:41px;
}

a:hover.submit_choices{
    background-image:url('Images/web_buttons.jpg');
    background-position: -162px -373px;
    position:fixed;
    top:3px;
    right:3px;
    width:164px;
    height:41px;

}

a.navigation_left{
    background-image:url('Images/web_buttons.jpg');
    background-position: 0px -413px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:6px;
    left:3px;
    width:134px;
    height:19px;
}

a:hover.navigation_left{
    background-image:url('Images/web_buttons.jpg');
    background-position: -134px -413px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:6px;
    left:3px;
    width:134px;
    height:19px;
}

a.navigation_right{
    background-image:url('Images/web_buttons.jpg');
    background-position: 0px -435px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:6px;
    right:3px;
    width:104px;
    height:19px;
}

a:hover.navigation_right{
    background-image:url('Images/web_buttons.jpg');
    background-position: -134px -435px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:6px;
    right:3px;
    width:104px;
    height:19px;
}

/*conten*/
#content{
    position:relative;
    top:55px;
    z-index:-3;
}
```

With this, I can only select the second radio button, the first one cannot be selected. The weird thing is, if I remove the break between the inputs, it works perfectly. Or I can leave the break there, and remove the 'helloworld' after the form, and it works too.

Anyone have any ideas or see anything wrong? I want to have the buttons on top of each other and I need to have other text underneath..

The CSS code is here

Comment: Copy-paste your code from the question to the blank html-file and see yourself that it does work.

Comment: paste in your CSS please

Comment: Which browsers is this happening in?

Comment: I added my full code and CSS, this is in Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have `z-index:-3`?  You're telling the browser to put the content behind other layers...

Comment: I made a page with his code above and did some tests, and this line is what is causing the problem, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS is almost definitely at fault here.  Looks like there's a child node that is being selected (`<br />`) when you don't mean it to be.  Could also be happening from Javascript.